# parse error in the composer.phar file

Tags: php, json, composer-php

I was using Composer perfectly, but now when a try any command I got this error:

> [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
>     "C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar" does not contain valid JSON
>     Parse error on line 1:
>     #!/usr/bin/env php<
>     ^
>     Expected one of: 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['

I already tried reinstall Composer, but nothing changes.
Any idea??

Comment: Did you install it on cygwin or similiar and now trying to run it using the windows command line

Comment: Nops... I use XAMPP and installed Composer by Composer-Setup.exe

Comment: Same issue here, did you managed to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and it took a while before it was fixed for me. Just in case other people find this topic i still want to provide the answer that fixed for me.

I also use Windows + wamp but the mistake with in the environment variables..... i was stupid enough to create a "composer" environment variable DO NOT DO THIS or rename it to something else in case you did.

Found the answer here
https://github.com/composer/getcomposer.org/issues/43

After renaming it worked again.

Comment: THANK YOU! 2019 and being useful!